# SML currying and recursion

Tags: sml

I'm writing functions to return max and min of a list

Since the code is the same except for one function call, I'm trying to not duplicate code

```
fun cur f f2 x=case x of
    []=>raise Empty
    |[x]=>x
    |x::xs=>f(x,f2(xs))
fun min x=cur Int.min min x
fun max x=cur Int.max max x
```

it feels having min refer to itself in declaration isn't good style

Any suggestions on how to improve the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `fun` is recursive by default.  Thus you are correct you don't need to make an explicit recursive reference:

```
fun cur f x = case x of
    [] => raise Empty
  | [x] => x
  | x::xs => f(x, cur f xs)
fun min x = cur Int.min x
fun max x = cur Int.max x
```

This is a general case of a fold.  Take a look at foldr and foldl in [the standard library](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html).  There are also more efficient ways to do this, in particular by making your function tail recursive.  That is always a nice exercise!